# Minix won't boot because of SDL

Tags: sdl, qemu, minix

I have tried literally everything that I was able to find in google and stackoverflow but I am still getting this error message. I use Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon and I have downloaded latest version of SDL - 2.0.4 but my Minix still won't boot.

```
marc@E540 ~/Downloads $ qemu-system-x86_64 minix203.img 
Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting
```

I know about -curses flag but I want to solve this issue.

Comment: Are your $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY environment variables set?

Comment: I have set it but for be 100% sure, how do I check if it is set?

Comment: From a terminal, type env.

Comment: DISPLAY=:0, 
XAUTHORITY=/home/marc/.Xauthority So its fine, but how can I check if SDL is installed properly?